# Ejabberd sequential vs parallel server

Tags: erlang, elixir, ejabberd, scalability, erlang-otp

As defined in Joe's book a TCP parallel server handle connections like this :

```
{ok, Listen}=gen_tcp:listen(....),
spawn(fun() ->parallel(Listen) end).

parallel(Listen) ->
{ok, Socket}=gen_tcp:accept(Listen),
spawn(fun() ->parallel(Listen) end),
doSomething(Socket).

doSomething(....) ->
....
```

This is logic, when a listener accept a connection, it spawns a process for listening to new incoming connections before handling this accepted connection, this is the parallelism rule, ok good.
in EJABBERD module ejabberd_listener.erl who represents the network layer of the server this is what i found:

```
case listen_tcp(Port, SockOpts) of
    {ok, ListenSocket} ->
.... 
    
    accept(ListenSocket, Module, State, Sup, Interval, Proxy), 

.... 
accept(ListenSocket, Module,... ) ->

case gen_tcp:accept(ListenSocket) of
    {ok, Socket} ->
%%%% a lot of work
....
accept(ListenSocket, Module,.... );
```

So this is a sequential listener and it runs slower than parallel, so why they don't use the parallel mechanism for more efficiency and performance ? iam new in ejabberd and i may missing something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you are talking about this code: [1].

In that case, if you look more closely, a bit further, the function `start_connection` is called[2].
Inside that function a dynamic supervisor is used and a child is added [3]. You do not use the `spawn` primitive here, but it's abstract by the `supervisor:start_child` function[4].

So in short, yes, each connection is handled concurrently, except here each process is added to a dynamic supervisor, instead of plain processes created by the spawn primitive.

[1] https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/c3169e9eeab15f47b33a14a6b93cec67c38193a6/src/ejabberd_listener.erl#L235

[2] https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/c3169e9eeab15f47b33a14a6b93cec67c38193a6/src/ejabberd_listener.erl#L266

[3] https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/c3169e9eeab15f47b33a14a6b93cec67c38193a6/src/ejabberd_listener.erl#L316

[4] http://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/sup_princ.html